# java.sql.SQLException Path to 'path' does not exist

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, error-handling, path

I am writing this because I created a simple Login `GUI` App to test `sqlite` database as I am a student of Database Systems and new to it, I used java through eclipse, whenever I run the Application this message

> java.sql.SQLException path to c:user//path does not exist

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hjrv.png)

I have searched a lot on google but couldn't find the solution there is a similar question on stackoverflow but there were not enough answer related to my problem, I want to know how to change the code to make the Application work and connect to database?

Any help will be much appreciated.Thanks

Here is the code:

```
package dbms;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class dbConnection {

Connection conn = null;

public static Connection dbConnector(){

    try{
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:‪‪‪C:\\Users\\chusm\\workspace\\DBMS\\SQlite\\DBMS.sqlite");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Successful!!!");
        return conn;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: inside of the catch block, do a line `e.printStackTrace();` and post that here. It might help with debugging.

Comment: @RyanZink no that is the correct way to get a connection from `DriverManager`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got some weird whitespace action going on in your url (between "jdbc:sqlite" and "C:"

Please copy paste this exact code in your project and run it (I only removed the weird whitespace, the rest is exactly like your code)

```
package dbms;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class StackOverflowExample {

    Connection conn = null;

    public static Connection dbConnector() {

        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\chusm\\workspace\\DBMS\\SQlite\\DBMS.sqlite");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Successful!!!");
            return conn;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection connection = dbConnector();
    }

}
```

Comment: open a IDE and write

    String x = ""; 

and inside "" paste the contents of the url that you posted above
you will notice the weird whitespace that i am talking about 

it looks like 

        String x = "jdbc:sqlite:\u202A\u202A\u202AC:\\\\Users\\\\chusm\\\\workspace\\\\DBMS\\\\SQlite\\\\DBMS.sqlite";

those invisible unicode characters were the problem

Comment: Now I understood, Actually Eclipse was not letting me save or compile the program and asked me if i want to save it using unicode UTF-8 something like this and I saved it this way maybe that created the problem.
Thanks a lot for your precious time and help.

Comment: [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4LHSq.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4LHSq.png) @Alexandru this is what I am talking about do you know why this error appears and what does it mean.
This error appeared when I initialized a String with my path statement and run the program.

Comment: I suspect that the place where you copied the original url from had the strange whitespace or maybe the file explorer where you copied it from.

Whenever you get a message like that it's a good hint that you have invisible characters going on and you should inspect the new additions to the file.